# Kivy and Twisted for Android connection drops

Tags: android, kivy, twisted

I'm making a very simple android app with kivy. 
The app connects to a twisted server and replies. 
On my laptop everything is ok, connection and reply.
But with android, connection seem to drops instantly and I got this error message:

### Failure: twisted.spread.pb.PBConnectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : None.

Android:

```
factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
connector = reactor.connectTCP(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT, factory)
d = factory.getRootObject()
d.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("get_msg"))
d.addCallback(lambda data: self.get_request_answer(data))
d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: ' + str(reason.value))
d.addCallback(lambda _: connector.disconnect())
```

Server:

```
class SVR(pb.Root):
    def remote_get_msg(self):
        return 'hello'

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print reason

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Connection success! Connected to:", self.transport.getPeer().host, ':', self.transport.getPeer().port

class Twin_ServerApp(App):
    label = None

    def build(self):
        self.label = Label(text="server started\n")
        reactor.listenTCP(SERVER_PORT, pb.PBServerFactory(SVR()))
        return self.label
```

none of connectionLost and connectionMade functions seem to be call

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: How does the Twisted test suite fare on Android?  Upstream Twisted development doesn't support or test on that platform.

Comment: I've certainly heard people using twisted with python-for-android successfully but I've also heard horror stories. If you can use a more general connection protocol besides PB that would be best. https://blog.kivy.org/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/

Comment: @notorious.no Thanks to both of you, I solved my problem by using a simpler protocol like https://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html